# How to set a combo box to a specific item with the press of a button (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, combobox

I'm a beginner so please excuse the dumb question.

So basically I have a "Dummy" Button that creates a new Patient by filling in Name, Age, Date etc.
But I don't know how to make it so that the combobox also gets set to a specific item. Can yall help me out? The combobox is second to last, code looks like this:

```vb
Private Sub Btn_dummy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_dummy.Click
    Me.Txt_Name.Text = "Mustermann"
    Me.Txt_Vorname.Text = "Max"
    Me.Dtp_Gebdat.Value = Today().AddDays(-365 * 12)
    Me.Txt_Strasse.Text = "Musterstrasse"
    Me.Txt_Hausnr.Text = "123A"
    Me.Mtb_Plz.Text = "12345"
    Me.Txt_Ort.Text = "Musterort"
    Me.Cmb_Krankenkasse = 
    Me.Txt_Versnr.Text = "987654"
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify what is the DataSource of `Cmb_Krankenkasse`. Just strings? How did you fill it? Test with `Cmb_Krankenkasse.SelectedIndex = Cmb_Krankenkasse.FindString("Some value")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on how you've setup your combobox. If you added the options through the designer then you would want to use SelectedIndex.

```
Me.Cmb_Krankenkasse.SelectedIndex = 1 ' Or whatever index you want to select
```

If you are using a binding to populate your combobox then you could use SelectedItem.

```
Me.Cmb_Krankenkasse.SelectedItem = selectedPersonEntry
```

Either way you're going to set the Selected property of the combobox.

Example:

```
Private Sub Btn_dummy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_dummy.Click
    Me.Txt_Name.Text = "Mustermann"
    Me.Txt_Vorname.Text = "Max"
    Me.Dtp_Gebdat.Value = Today().AddDays(-365 * 12)
    Me.Txt_Strasse.Text = "Musterstrasse"
    Me.Txt_Hausnr.Text = "123A"
    Me.Mtb_Plz.Text = "12345"
    Me.Txt_Ort.Text = "Musterort"
    Me.Cmb_Krankenkasse.SelectedIndex = 1
    Me.Txt_Versnr.Text = "987654"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed! thank you very much.
I even tried to use SelectedIndex I just used it very wrong lol

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The user should choose something from the comboBox, right?
It is best to subscribe to the selected item event.
it works like this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Form1
    Private gesetzliche_KK As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({"Viactiv", "Barmer", "Techniker"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        gesetzliche_KK = CStr(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You should, at least for this English-speaking forum, translate your variable names into English. Du solltest, zumindest für dieses englisch-sprachige Forum, deine Variablennamen ins Englische übertragen.

[image: How to subscribe an event]