# Show the right column on a form through buttons from a different form

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, combobox

In my access database, I have 2 seperate forms. The first one has 5 buttons and the other one is filled with comboboxes. Each combobox has 5 different columns to chose from.
I wanna be able to just click on a button and be sent to the other from with the correct column/data piece being shown on my combobox.
[The left one is the first form with the buttons, the right one is the form with all of the comboboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JkFl.png)

Comment: So far I have tried putting "If Me.Button1_Click Then Me.Combobox1 = 1 into the vba code of my first form. I also forgot to mention that the 2nd form is connected via a macro to the first one, so no matter which button you click, you are sent to the 2nd form however all f the comboboxes are empty since my basis value for all of them is 0

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65996597/how-to-set-a-combo-box-to-a-specific-item-with-the-press-of-a-button-visual-bas so take a look